# MS SSRS Report Builder - Semantic query compilation failed

Tags: reporting-services, sqlreportingservice

```
Semantic query compilation failed: e InvalidParameterValueCardinality The parameter "Region1" requires a single value. 
However, the value provided for the parameter is a set. (SemanticQuery ''). (rsSemanticQueryEngineError)
----------------------------
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
```

I was getting this error on MS SSRS. I have two dropdowns which can select multiple values. It's working for single value. If I select multiple  values I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by setting "equals" to "In a List".

here is the steps

In DataSets -> Query Designer -> Filter -> Any of section click on equals then select In a List

[image]